# Comparing lengths of words in strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need to find the longest word in a string and print that word.
1.) Ask user to enter sentence separated by spaces.
2.)Find and print the longest word. If two or more words are the same length than print the first word.

this is what I have so far

```
def maxword(splitlist):      #sorry, still trying to understand loops
    for word in splitlist:
        length = len(word)
        if ??????

wordlist = input("Enter a sentence: ")
splitlist = wordlist.split()

maxword(splitlist)
```

I'm hitting a wall when trying to compare the lenghts of words in a sentance. I'm a student who's been using python for 5 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def longestWord(sentence):
    longest = 0   # Keep track of the longest length
    word = ''     # And the word that corresponds to that length
    for i in sentence.split():
        if len(i) > longest:
            word = i
            longest = len(i)
    return word

>>> s = 'this is a test sentence with some words'
>>> longestWord(s)
'sentence'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [max](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max) with a key:

```
def max_word(splitlist):      
    return max(splitlist.split(),key=len) if splitlist.strip() else "" # python 2


def max_word(splitlist): 
    return max(splitlist.split()," ",key=len) # python 3
```

Or use a try/except as suggested by jon clements:

```
def max_word(splitlist):
    try:
        return max(splitlist.split(),key=len)
    except ValueError:
        return " "
```

Comment: Python 3.4 has a [`default` keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max) that is returned when the iterable is empty.

Comment: @kroolik True, did not see the python3 tag

Comment: You'd be better off using `try: return max(splitlist.split(), key=len)` with an `except ValueError: return ''` having no words seems to me to be the exceptional case - since `.split()` by default will automatically handle the stripping and multiple split delimiters... (the `if splitlist.strip()` seems a bit of a waste)

Comment: @JonClements, `maxword("")`,`maxword(" ")` will throw errors in python2. I just wanted to add a simple concise way to catch those cases similar to the python3 version. I don't think the OP is really checking for empty strings, I just added it for completeness but sure a try/except is probably a better way to go.

Comment: @Padraic all I'm saying is that something like [this](https://gist.github.com/joncle/dbe52ad378d5c2f33ddf) will work in anything 2.5+ and doesn't explicitly special case check for *empty* strings (plus - I think your 3.x version is broken as it'll be comparing the length of a list of words with a single character)

Comment: @JonClements, yep, I understood you ;) I will add a try/except for completeness

Comment: And finally I think your `" "` should be `""` as `len(max(''.split(), ' ', key=len))` will be 1 - I imagine it should be 0 :) (or as @kroolix has pointed out, the best possible solution specific to 3.4 is `return max(text.split(), key=len, default=0)`

Comment: @JonClements, nope :) using " " returns an empty string using "" returns an empty list, I preferred returning an empty string as that is what is going to be returned from the function normally

Comment: And also, as already mentioned, it's just a bit of coincidence it works using the two param method of `max`, eg: try `max(['test'], 'xx', key=len)` - while really nitpicking, and I can't see immediately how it'll catch someone out... it's still a bit *ugh*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no `""` is an *empty* string... `" "` is a string containing a single space (hence has a length of one instead of zero) - a distinct difference...

Comment: @JonClements, `print(max_words(""))` -> `[]` using `""` `print(max_words(""))` using `" "` will output a `" "`. I don't think outputting a list is better

Comment: Well, if you really wanted to: `return max(text.split(), '', key=len) or ''` then? :p

Comment: @JonClements, you have way too much time on your hands ;)

Comment: Just trying to get another active member to the 20k mark :)

Answer (score 1):

You're going in the right direction. Most of your code looks good, you just need to finish the logic to determine which is the longest word. Since this seems like a homework question I don't want to give you the direct answer (even though everyone else has which I think is useless for a student like you), but there are multiple ways to solve this problem.

You're getting the length of each word correctly, but what do you need to compare each length against? Try to say the problem aloud and how you'd personally solve the problem aloud. I think you'll find that your english description translates nicely to a python version.

Another solution that doesn't use an `if` statement might use the built-in python function `max` which takes in a list of numbers and returns the max of them. How could you use that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly where I was getting stuck. I knew what I wanted to do I just didn't know how to implement it. Asking for help is my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nlargest from heapq module

```
import heapq
heapq.nlargest(1, sentence.split(), key=len)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = raw_input("Enter sentence: ")
words = sentence.split(" ")
maxlen = 0
longest_word = ''
for word in words:
    if len(word) > maxlen:
          maxlen = len(word)
          longest_word = word
print(word, maxlen)
```